# How to format a table made by dbms_output.put_line PL/SQL?

Tags: oracle, plsql, format

I have a procedure that produces a table in the `spool`:

```
create procedure.....
......
loop
...
dbms_output.put_line(p_taskno||'   '||p_descrip||'  '||p_hrs||' '||p_start_date);
.........
```

The output is correct, however not well formatted:

```
***************************************                                         
ABC Company         Projects:                                                   
Project: 5555                                                                   
TaskNo  Description      Hours StartDate                                        
_____________________________________________                                   
11      Prototype New Screens  30 23-AUG-06                                     
12      Convert Data Files  10.5 15-SEP-06                                      
13      Create Test Plan  15 14-AUG-06                                          
62      Develop Enterprise Model  280 26-OCT-06                                 
_____________________________________________                                   
Number of Tasks: 4                                                              
Total Project Hours: 335.5
```

I cannot use `column description format a20 word_wrapped` because the table is the result of the `dbms_output.put_line`. How can I format it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to work out the maximum size of the column and then pad the output with spaces.

So you want `taskno` to align with its header, that's six characters.  Because it's a numeric you'll want it to align on the right:

```
lpad(to_char(taskno), 6)
```

Whereas Description is a string, so you'll want to align it on the left

```
rpad(p_description, 30)
```

Use these functions on the elements of the header too, to get the neatest output.